# Deciding on the training sequences for RNN/LSTM language model

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, natural-language, recurrent-neural-network, language-models

In a character language model, text is seen as a stream of characters. Say we have a training text as a string `s`, with length `len(s)`. For training a language model, I've seen people come up with the training sequences in several ways:

- fix a sequence length, say `n=5`, and chop up the training text by
  `n` to form a training set like `(s[0:5], s[1:6]), (s[5:10], s[6:11]), ...`, where each tuple `(x, y)` is an input, output pair, and we have a total of `len(s)/n` training examples. An advantage is we don't have to set a BPTT truncation parameter, because we always unroll the RNN `n` times and do BPTT exactly (provided `n` is small enough).  This is done, for example by [Karpathy](https://gist.github.com/karpathy/d4dee566867f8291f086#file-min-char-rnn-py-L111).
- everything else as the above, except the sliding window takes a stride of `1`, instead of `n`. This gives a training set like `(s[0:5], s[1:6]), (s[1:6], s[2:7]), ...`, with size `len(s)-n+1` (which can be much larger than the previous method). This kind of windowing is used in training traditional n-gram language models, for example [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/yoavg/d76121dfde2618422139).
- just use sentences in the text as training examples, rather than sequences of fixed length `n`. This is done for word level RNN language model in [this blog post](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-2-implementing-a-language-model-rnn-with-python-numpy-and-theano/), where a training example looks like `('SETENCE_START Hello world !','Hello world ! SETENCE_END')`. Since the sentences can be very long, a BPTT truncation parameter is needed; we also get less training data with this method, if the sentences are very long.

Does anybody have good insights as which method to use? I consulted the [original paper by Mikolov](http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/research/groups/speech/publi/2010/mikolov_interspeech2010_IS100722.pdf), but couldn't figure out exactly which method they used.

Comment: I don't buy your argument that you get less training data using method 3. It's the same data in all three cases. Method 2 reuses the data multiple times but that's not the same as having more data.